# Boost program_options with boost::optional

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to write an CLI using `boost::program_options` to an existing codebase that utilizes a lot of `boost::optional` arguments so I would like to parse `boost::optional`'s from the command line. If it is not specified, the result is `boost::none`, and if it is specified I get an initialized value.

When I attempt to do this using a custom Boost validator, I get a `bad_any_cast`. Below is a MCVE of the problem.

I have a class

```
class MyClass {                                                                                                     
public:                                                                                                       
    int x;                                                                                                    
    MyClass(const int a) : x(a) {};                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
};
```

and a custom Boost validator for this class. This style of validator was taken straight from the boost docs.

```
void validate(boost::any& v, const std::vector<std::string>& values,                                          
          MyClass* target_type, int) {                                                                          

    v = boost::any(boost::optional<MyClass>(boost::in_place(1)));                                                   
}
```

Lastly, my main function, which creates a simple parser.

```
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>                                                                          
#include <boost/optional.hpp>                                                                                 
#include <boost/optional/optional_io.hpp>                                                                     
#include <boost/utility/in_place_factory.hpp> 

int main(int argc, char** argv) {                                                                             
    po::options_description desc("");                                                                         
    desc.add_options()                                                                                        
        ("MyClass", po::value<boost::optional<MyClass>>()->default_value(boost::none, ""), "MyClass");        

    po::variables_map args;                                                                                   

    po::store(po::parse_command_line(argc, argv, desc), args);                                                

}
```

When I do not pass the `--MyClass` options on the command line, the code runs successfully. However, if I pass the `--MyClass` option, I get a `bad_any_cast`

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::bad_any_cast> >'
  what():  boost::bad_any_cast: failed conversion using boost::any_cast
```

I stepped through with GDB and this is being thrown in the `MyClass` `any_cast`, yet if I write similar code outside of `boost::program_options`, it works succesfuly.

For example, the following code, that casts the same `boost::optional` to `boost::any` and then casts it back, runs without error.

```
#include <iostream>                                                                                           
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>                                                                          
#include <boost/optional.hpp>                                                                                 
#include <boost/optional/optional_io.hpp>                                                                     
#include <boost/utility/in_place_factory.hpp>                                                                 

namespace po = boost::program_options;                                                                        

class MyClass {                                                                                              
public:                                                                                                       
    int x;                                                                                                    
    MyClass(const int a) : x(a) {};                                                                           
};                                                                                                            

int f(boost::any& v) {                                                                                        
    v = boost::any(boost::optional<MyClass>(boost::in_place(1)));                                             
}                                                                                                             


int main(int argc, char** argv) {                                                                             

    boost::any v;                                                                                             
    f(v);                                                                                                     
    boost::any_cast<boost::optional<MyClass>>(v);                                                             
}
```

I know that `program_options` supports `default_value` so I could use an if statement to wrap the base value in an optional  after parsing but I think it would be much cleaner to achive this using the custom validator approach above.

Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions on how to go about fixing this?

Comment: Have you tried changing your default value from `boost::none` to `boost::optional<MyClass>()`? `boost::none` isn't the same type as `boost::optional<MyClass>()` so that would cause the any cast to fail

Comment: `boost::none` is actually compatible with `boost::optional<T>` and indicates that the optional does not contain a value (i.e. `boost::optional<T> v.reset() == boost::none` will evaluate to true). Furthermore, the code works when the `any_cast` is applied to `boost::none`, just not when it is applied to anything other than `boost::none`. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The validation function does not take an optional. This is implied by the fact that the type argument (`target_type`) is `MyClass*`, not `optional<MyClass>*`. [docs](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2ab2f0daa71303d2)

> The function takes four parameters. The first is the storage for the value, and in this case is either empty or contains an instance of the magic_number class. The second is the list of strings found in the next occurrence of the option. The remaining two parameters are needed to workaround the lack of partial template specialization and partial function template ordering on some compilers.

Here's my take on it:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3b522e5353c2fe6f)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/optional.hpp>
#include <boost/optional/optional_io.hpp>
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
#include <boost/utility/in_place_factory.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

namespace po = boost::program_options;

struct MyClass {
    int x;
    MyClass(int a) : x(a){};

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, MyClass const& mc) {
        return os << "MyClass(" << mc.x << ")";
    }
};

void validate(boost::any &v, const std::vector<std::string> &values, MyClass * /*target_type*/, int) {
    v = MyClass(std::stoi(values.front()));
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    po::options_description desc("");
    desc.add_options()("MyClass", po::value<boost::optional<MyClass> >()->default_value(boost::none, ""), "MyClass");

    po::variables_map args;
    store(parse_command_line(argc, argv, desc), args);
    notify(args);

    std::cout << "Arg: " << args["MyClass"].as<boost::optional<MyClass> >() << "\n";
}
```

For:

```
./a.out --MyClass 42
./a.out --MyClass no_chill
./a.out
```

Prints

```
+ ./a.out --MyClass 42
Arg:  MyClass(42)
+ ./a.out --MyClass no_chill
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'
  what():  stoi
+ ./a.out
Arg: --
```

### Bonus

Taking a hints from [the docs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/program_options/howto.html#id-1.3.31.6.10) I think you could make it more elegant:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    po::options_description desc("");

    boost::optional<MyClass> my_option;
    desc.add_options()("MyClass", po::value(&my_option), "MyClass");

    po::variables_map args;
    store(parse_command_line(argc, argv, desc), args);
    notify(args);

    std::cout << "Arg: " << my_option << "\n";
}
```

Removing all the error-prone repeating of types and names.
**Note:** this does not work for boost versions lower than 1.65, and the user will see a static assert error coming from "lexical_cast.hpp" when compiling (see [release notes](https://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_65_0.html) for 1.65).

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cf08cf4b2bacdb4b)</kbd>**

Still the same output.

Comment: I can't believe I missed something so trivially obvious; thanks for the detailed answer!

Comment: @RemyPrechelt I'd identify this as the problem with duck-typing (`boost::any` in this case). Cheers!